# ansible parse date using regex search

Tags: regex, ansible

I am trying parse month,day and year from show clock output using regex_search, getting error.

from cli of a router i see this -

```
sh clock
16:22:12.975 PST Wed Jan 27 2021
```

```
    - name: Run sh log
      cisco.ios.ios_command:
           commands:
             - sh clock
      register: output1

    - name: sh clock output
      debug:
        msg: "{{ output1.stdout_lines | regex_search('(Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?|Apr(il)?|May|Jun(e)?|Jul(y)?|Aug(ust)?|Sep(tember)?|Oct(ober)?|Nov(ember)?|Dec(ember)?)^\s+\d{1,2}\s+\d{4}' }}"
```

error

```
The offending line appears to be:

      debug:
        msg: "{{ output1.stdout_lines | regex_search('(Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?|Apr(il)?|May|Jun(e)?|Jul(y)?|Aug(ust)?|Sep(tember)?|Oct(ober)?|Nov(ember)?|Dec(ember)?)\s+\d{1,2}\s+\d{4}' }}"
                                                                                                                                                                              ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"
```

desired/wanted debug msg is below ,i don't want time, just need month day and year

```
Jan 27 2021
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `regex_replace`. Put the regex into a separate single-quoted variable. For example, the task below does the job

```yaml
    - name: sh clock output
      debug:
        msg: "{{ output1.stdout_lines|regex_replace(my_regex, my_replace) }}"
      vars:
        my_regex: '^(.*)(Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?|Apr(il)?|May|Jun(e)?|Jul(y)?|Aug(ust)?|Sep(tember)?|Oct(ober)?|Nov(ember)?|Dec(ember)?)\s+(\d{1,2})\s+(\d{4})$'
        my_replace: '\2 \14 \15'
```

---

The splitting is simpler. For example, the task below gives the same result

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ arr[-3] }} {{ arr[-2] }} {{ arr[-1] }}"
      vars:
        arr: "{{ output1.stdout_lines.split() }}"
```

See [Handling dates and times](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#handling-dates-and-times)